# aggregate data frame and remove NA

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to reshape it so that I only have one row for each observation `obs`. Here is the example data:

```
data <- data.frame("obs" = c('1','1','1','2','2'),
                   "value1" = c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                   "value2" = c(NA,NA,3,1,NA),
                   "value3" = c(NA,2,NA,NA,5))
```

data looks like this:

```
  obs value1 value2 value3
   1      1     NA     NA
   1     NA     NA      2
   1     NA      3     NA
   2     NA      1     NA
   2     NA     NA      5
```

and I want to reshape it into:

```
obs  value1  value2  value3
1       1      3       2
2       NA     1       5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be sure you will never have two rows with the same obs and an entry for a given value column?  If so, joran's answer is great.  Otherwise, you'll have to decide how you want to handle them if you want only one row per `obs` value.

Comment: You're right. Now that I used Joran's code I found that for some obs codes I have additional entries for values. In this case how can I get mean of those values to have only one row per obs?

Comment: You'd modify the second line (`else` statement) of his function to return the `mean(x[!is.na(x)])` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do this, using **plyr**:

```
foo <- function(x){
    if (all(is.na(x))) return(NA)
    else return(x[!is.na(x)])
}

ddply(dat,.(obs),colwise(foo))
```

And this of course assumes that you really do only have at most one non-NA value in each column for each value of `obs`.

If this isn't the case, and you want to take the mean of multiple values, you might try doing as Justin suggested:

```
mean(x[!is.na(x)])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(dat)

dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), by = obs]
```

If you have multiple entries per value for a given observation, this will use R's recycling logic to fill the rest.

Answer (score 2):

A base solution:

```
out <- lapply(split(data, data$obs), function(x) {
    ans <- lapply(x[, -1], na.omit)
    data.frame(obs = x[1, 1], t(sapply(ans, "[", 1)))
})

do.call(rbind, out)

## > do.call(rbind, out)
##   obs value1 value2 value3
## 1   1      1      3      2
## 2   2     NA      1      5
```